# Logitech Marble Mouse - KDE

Tags: debian, kde, mouse

I have a new Debian 12 system (KDE on X11, not Wayland) with a Logitech Marble Mouse. Need help setting it up so that I can scroll using the right small button and ball. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Marble_Mouse

The following old and trusty config doesn't seem to be having any effect:

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf 
# REFER: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Marble_Mouse
#       - - - Logitech Marble Mouse Settings - - -
#
#       The Logitech Marble Mouse buttons are mapped [A-D] from left to right: 
#       A (large); B (small) |  C (small); D (large). 
#
#       Preferred options for right-handed usage:
#       A = normal click [1]  
#       B = middle-click [2] 
#       C = middle-click [2]
#       D = right-click [3]
#       Hold button B while rolling trackball to emulate wheel-scrolling. 
#       Pressing both large buttons simultaneously (b) produces a "back" action.

# Ids for actions.
# 1     Large button left       normal click
#  2    Both large buttons      middle-click  †
#  3    Large button right      right-click
#  4    (not a button)  -
#  5    (not a button)  -
#  6    (not a button)  -
#  7    (not a button)  -
#  8    Small button left       browser back
#  9    Small button right      browser forward

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
        MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"

#       Physical button #s:     A b D - - - - B C    
#       Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 2"   right-hand placement
#       Option "ButtonMapping" "3 8 1 4 5 6 7 2 2"   left-hand placement
#       b = A & D 
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10"

#       EmulateWheel: Use Marble Mouse trackball as mouse wheel 
#       Factory Default: 8; Use 9 for right side small button
        Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "9"
        Option        "MiddleEmulation"     "true"
        # Option        "HorizontalScrolling" "false"
#       EmulateWheelInertia: How far (in pixels) the pointer must move to
#       generate button press/release events in wheel emulation mode.
#       Factory Default: 50
        Option "EmulateWheelInertia" "10"

#       Axis Mapping: Enable vertical [ZAxis] and horizontal [XAxis] scrolling
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
        Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"

#       Emulate3Buttons: Required to interpret simultaneous press of two large
#       buttons, A & D, as a seperate command, b.
#       Factory Default: true
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
EndSection
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [libinput driver](https://discuss.kde.org/t/logitech-marble-mouse-scroll-setup/10432/9) was being used, and a different configuration (also mentioned in  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Marble_Mouse) was therefore needed.

The linked steps are:

1. Install xf86-input-libinput
2. Edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-libinput.conf. Append the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier   "Marble Mouse"
  MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
  Driver       "libinput"
  Option       "ScrollMethod"    "button"
  Option       "ScrollButton"    "8"
  Option       "MiddleEmulation" "true"
EndSection
```